# gpg consuming 100% cpu

Tags: centos, gpg, cpu-usage

I'm using gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.22. I'm using it to encrypt my backup files. However, I have observed that once it start encryption, it uses 100% cpu. Any way to avoid this? It's necessary and on priority.

From https://blog.wefixit.at/gpg-high-cpu-usage/ suggestion, I have tried with :

```
    < ${GNUPGHOME:-~/.gnupg}/pubring.gpg gpg –list-packets | awk -F= -v 
oldoff=-1 -v keyid=unset ‘
/^# off=/{ off = $2 + 0 }
/^:public key/{
if (oldoff>-1) { print (off – oldoff) ” ” keyid };
oldoff = off; keyid = “unset”;
}
/keyid:/ {if (keyid == “unset”) { keyid = $1; } }
END { print (off – oldoff) ” ” keyid ; };’ | sort -n
```

However, there is only one key in my keyring

```
    0       keyid: XXFCC7910785XXXX
```

Nothing working for me as of now. Any way to avoid this or limiting number of cpu utilized by gpg. Any immediate help will be appreciated.

Comment: I fixed the same problem yesterday. I followed the solution [here](https://dev.gnupg.org/T3972), which is also referenced in the blog post you linked. Part of the problem may be that the blog post (and your quoted command) is full of typos. It incorrectly uses smart quotes, and modifies hyphens and dashes. Try the command from the [original source](https://dev.gnupg.org/T3972#127356) instead.

Comment: @Sparhawk, I run the command from the original source you mentioned. Same result.

Comment: Hmm… okay. I'm not sure then. If you don't get anything helpful here, you might consider posting on the gpg forum/bugtracker.